# Can a lexical grammar be defined using productions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction

I'm watching a course on compilers that uses regexps to define a grammar for lexical analyzer (lexer) which uses this regexp to configure finite automaton. Only when the course gets to the syntax analyzer (parser) section the terms specific to context-free grammar like productions, terminals and non-terminals are introduced. Which leads to a conclusion that these are only used during syntax analysis.

However, the EcmaScript spec [defines productions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar) for the lexer:

> Productions of the lexical and RegExp grammars are distinguished by
>   having two colons “::” as separating punctuation. The lexical and
>   RegExp grammars share some productions.

So can the grammar for the lexer also be specified using productions with terminal and non-terminal symbols and not solely regexps?

[This grammar tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_syntax_analysis.htm) also mentions that context-free-grammar (CFG) is a superset of Regular Grammar so it seems that the answer to my question is "yes". I'd appreciate a little bit of explanation. Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is "yes", of course; it's just much simpler to work with regular grammars at the tokenizer level. When you work with Parse Expression Grammars, there is no tokenizer level, so the entire language is expressed at the higher level.

Comment: Also note that JavaScript is a particularly complicated language, and that the embedded regular expression literal syntax is a big reason for that.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks, _it's just much simpler to work with regular grammars at the tokenizer level_ - yes, but from what I understand instead of regural grammar (regexps) the ecmascript standard defined a CFG (productions) for the lexer. Am I confused?

Comment: Again, JavaScript is a very very complicated grammar. The syntax of regular expression literals (`/foo|bar/` etc) and in particular the role of the `/` character means that the grammar has to have all sorts of special productions to deal with the ambiguities. Still, *most* of the lexical grammar can be described with simple regular expressions.

Comment: @Pointy, so to summarize - it is possible to use CFG instead of RG, but since RG is simpler it's usually used for the lexer. However, since EcmaScript has a complex syntax due to regexp literals the standard doesn't use RG and defines the grammar for both lexer and parser using CGF (productions)?

Comment: Yes, I think that's right. Really, JavaScript is not a good choice of "example language" for looking at basic parser implementation strategies as a beginner. Go with something like C or Java.

Comment: @Pointy, cool, thanks for the confirmation. The course I'm watching uses a made-up language to teach compiler theory. But I'm programming in JavaScript and my eventual goal is to understand the internals of TypeScript compiler which is largely based on the EcmaScript grammar. Hence I'm trying to understand it and correlate what the course teaches with what is in the EcmaScript spec. Besides, I haven't found any "intro into reading EcmaScript" guide, so it could be beneficial to create one :)

Comment: "*grammar be specified using productions and not solely regexps*" - I think you're confusing two things here. A grammar always consists of productions. In JS, we do have multiple grammars - like one for lexems, and one for JS regex literals. Neither of those is a regular grammar that can be expression using a regular expression.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, the topic is not easy so I indeed might be confused. What about [this article](http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/17-regex-grammars/#regular_expressions) that shows how regular expressions can be used for the grammar?

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi Yes, we can use different ways of writing productions (for the same grammar, even). Choices include [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus–Naur_form), [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_form), [ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus–Naur_form), [Syntax diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) and many others, also the various dialects of regular expressions. However, ECMAScript does not use regular expressions in their notation for their grammars. The mention of RegExp is just the name of the described grammar.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the links, I'll check it out. Do you know of any resources that "introduce" ecmascript spec?

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi [Dmitry Soshnikov](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/) explains ES3 and ES5 in detail. However, I don't think the spec is something that needs to be "introduced" to novices, it's not written to be read by end users.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks a lot for the resource link! Very interesting. I have one more question though :). The course I'm watching uses finite automaton and regural language (regexps) to process tokens. The CFG productions are processed using recursive descent parsing or backtracking. So does it mean that I can use these algorithms instead of finite automaton to construct tokens during lexical analysis?

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi Yes, you could, a finite automaton is just more efficient usually.

Comment: @Bergi, great, thanks, things get clearer now. Also, if you have time, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45694166/2545680) I'm asking what does the `symbol` term usually mean. After studying compilers for some time it now seems that it's not `symbol` in the context of `linker symbol tables`, but a `terminal` and a `non-terminal` symbol in the context of grammar productions. Appreciate any comment on that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been answered in comments, but unless it's a duplicate, it probably deserves an answer.

As in your own link, yes, any parser that handles a context-free grammar can also handle a regular grammar.  Context-free grammars are those recognized by a pushdown automaton (PDA), which is a strict superset<sup>1</sup> of those recognized by a finite state machine (FSM).  There is a good chapter on this [here](http://cs.brown.edu/~jes/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation_Chapter4.pdf), for instance.

(Note that a *regular language*, which I will call "RL" here although that's not a common abbreviation, is one that can be recognized by an FSM.  A *context free language* or CFL is one that can be recognized by a PDA.  Meanwhile a *regular grammar*, or RG, is one that recognizes regular languages, and a context-free grammar, or CFG, is one that recognizes context-free languages.  CFL, CFG, PDA, and FSM are all common and standard abbreviations; it's the RL and RG abbreviations I am using here that are not.  We also have RE or R.E., standing for Regular Expression, which is how we write our regular *language*—our RL—that we use to build the FSM that recognizes "words" in this RL.)

The reason we generally come up with some RL and write a small regular-expression-based FSM recognizer for this to turn input into tokens, then parse the tokens with a context-free grammar, is that this makes for smaller, simpler code construction.  Compilers that do not do extensive optimization tend to spend much of their time in the tokenizing code (though obviously this varies from language to language: e.g., some languages have complex type systems that can cause them to spend most of their time just doing type matching), so to the extent that we can make this small and fast, we come out ahead.

As [Bergi notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919640/can-a-lexical-grammar-be-defined-using-productions#comment78807642_45919640), the specific issue you're looking at in ECMAScript is the *syntax by which the source language expresses a regular expression*.  (Is that sentence too convoluted? :-) )  While a regular expression is something that can be *recognized by* an FSM (rather than a PDA), the syntax we use to *write* the regular expression need not itself be an RL—and in ECMAScript, it isn't.

In fact, using a mix of RL and CFL to encode REs is pretty typical.  For instance, in C, C++, and Python, RE handling is in a library, and we send the library routine a string, which it "compiles" into some FSM.  The string itself encodes the RE in a CFL, so the (runtime) compilation into an FSM can fail.  Some other languages, such as awk, raise the RE syntax into the grammar, but come up with a surrounding regular *language* in which to express it—such as /pattern/ with any embedded slashes within the pattern being encoded as `\/`.  By encoding the RE in an RL, these languages allow their FSM-based tokenizers to turn the entire RE into a single token, without using a CFG.  The token can then be compiled at compile time rather than run time (using a separate subroutine that takes the token apart again), and any compile-time grammar violation can be produced at awk "compile" time (which is runtime anyway).

ECMAScript simply chooses to be different.  Its language for its REs is not an RL, but is a CFL, so only a PDA, not an FSM, can recognize it.  Whether it could be handled in an awk-like fashion, I'm not sure: the CFL part is defined in section 21.2.1, and there is a surrounding RL in section 11.8.5.  As [Bergi notes again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919640/can-a-lexical-grammar-be-defined-using-productions/45927842?noredirect=1#comment78814704_45927842), the embedded CFL requires a PDA / CFG (e.g., the syntax in 21.2.1 has balanced parentheses: a disjunction embeds additional disjunctions, and requires a closing parenthesis afterward).

(Whew!  Too many TLAs!<sup>2</sup> :-) )

---

<sup>1</sup>This strict superset means there are many CFLs that cannot be recognized by an FSM.  A classic example is that FSMs cannot balance an arbitrary number of parentheses, while PDAs can.  If you pick some upper limit, such as "no more than 100 nested parentheses", you can generate a (rather alarmingly large) FSM that recognizes all inputs that have no more than 100 nested parentheses, yet nonetheless have balanced parentheses.

<sup>2</sup>TLA: Three (or occasionally Two) Letter Acronym.  See also ETLA, Extended Three Letter Acronym.

Comment: To avoid the TLAs, just write them out - using search&replace if it needs to be. It helps readability a lot, especially for those who are not accustomed to the terms.

Comment: You might want to note that you always need a CFG to parse a regular expression, regardless of the embedding. If embedded in a regular language as a pattern (like "anything between two slashes"), the parser cannot validate the regular expression, it can only recognise the pattern as one token.

Comment: @Bergi: I actually find the TLAs helpful sometimes, they "chunk" nicely (as a named idea). Surely there are simple REs that don't need a CFG to express, though. It's only the real ones we use in these languages that do (because they have unlimited balanced parentheses, for instance). But I'll edit the penultimate pre-footnote paragraph.

Comment: @torek, thanks a lot for your answer. Although I admit it's a bit difficult to grasp for the lack of sufficient background. I believe the paragraph starting with `The reason we generally come up with some...` is the answer to my question.